# Agregar y quitar elemento de un arreglo si se selecciona o deselecciona checkbox en Angular

Tags: array, angular, checkbox

Tengo datos que si se seleccionan en un `checkbox` y se presiona el botón de guardar se agregan en un arreglo, pero al momento de deseleccionar el elemento por medio del `checkbox` el elemento no se quita del arreglo.

Tengo esto en mi `html`:

```
 <form [formGroup]="form" #categoryForm="ngForm">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
           <mat-label>Nombre CV</mat-label>
           <input type="text" matInput formControlName="nombrecv">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-accordion>
           <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle *ngFor="let bloque of arregloBloques | keyvalue">
                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                     <mat-panel-title>
                          Bloque: {{bloque.key}}
                     </mat-panel-title>
                     <mat-panel-description>
                          Despliegue para obtener mayor información
                     </mat-panel-description>
                 </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                 <div *ngFor="let propiedad of arregloBloques[bloque.key] ">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="miDataInterior"
                           [(ngModel)]="propiedad.isSelected" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                           (change)="$event.target.checked ? agregar(propiedad.isSelected,propiedad.bloque, propiedad.atributo, propiedad.mapeo) :
                           quitar(propiedad.isSelected, propiedad.bloque, propiedad.atributo, propiedad.mapeo)">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">
                           <b>Bloque:</b>
                           {{propiedad.bloque}}
                           <b>Atributo:</b>
                           {{propiedad.atributo}}
                      </label>
                 </div>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
       </mat-accordion>
       <div class="col text-center">
            <button mat-raised-button class="botones" color="primary" [disabled]='!form.valid'
            (click)="PostConfiguracionPersonalizada()">Guardar
            </button>
       </div>
</form>
```

En mi `.ts` tengo lo siguiente:

```
 miDataInterior = [];

  agregar(visible: string, bloque: string, atributo: string, mapeo: string) {
    console.log(this.form.value.nombrecv)
    const data = {
      idDocente: 1,
      bloque: bloque,
      atributo: atributo,
      visible_cv_personalizado: visible,
      mapeo: mapeo,
      cv: 1,
      nombre_cv: this.form.value.nombrecv
    }

    let conf = this.miDataInterior.push(data);
    console.log(conf);
  }

  quitar(visible, bloque, atributo, mapeo) {
    const data = {
      idDocente: 1,
      bloque: bloque,
      atributo: atributo,
      visible_cv_personalizado: visible,
      mapeo: mapeo,
      cv: 1,
      nombre_cv: this.form.value.nombrecv
    }
    this.miDataInterior = this.miDataInterior.filter(s => s !== data);
    console.log(this.miDataInterior)
  }
```

Como dije antes, al seleccionar el checkbox los elementos se me agregar al arreglo en la función `agregar` , pero al momento de deseleccionar en la función `quitar` los elementos no se quitan del arreglo y me sigue saliendo lo mismo que cuando agregue. Lo que quiero es que cuando se deseleccione el checkbox los elementos agregados en un principio se puedan quitar. Sé que algo no está bien en mi función `quitar` he intentado varias cosas pero sigo con el mismo problema. Espero me puedan ayudar y les agradezco de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar haciendo cambios en mi función `quitar` cambiando el `filter` por un `splice`. Esto me permitió quitar el elemento del arreglo cuando deselecciono el `checkbox`. Mi función ahora quedó así:

```
quitar(atributo) {
    this.miDataInterior.splice(this.miDataInterior.indexOf(atributo), 1);
    console.log(this.miDataInterior)
}
```